# Error trying to copy a folder

Tags: java, io, copy

I'm currently trying to develop a file explorer program with commands(Like the CMD thingy). I'm currently getting errors while trying to copy a folder and I cannot find the problem.

```
public  class Action {

    public static void copy(String srcDestination, String desDestination) throws IOException{
        Scanner userEntry= new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;

        String sSource=srcDestination;
        String sDesignated=desDestination;


        Path pSource = Paths.get(sSource);
        Path pDesignated = Paths.get(sDesignated);
        File fSource= new File(sSource);
        File fDesignated= new File(sDesignated);

        if(!fSource.exists()){

            System.out.println("Source directory does not exist!");

        }
        else if (!fDesignated.exists()){
            System.out.println("Destination directory does not exist! Would you like to create it now? Y/N");
            userInput=userEntry.nextLine();


            if(userInput.equals("Y")||userInput.equals("y")){
                fDesignated.mkdir();
            }
            Files.copy(pSource, pDesignated, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);
        }
        Files.copy(pSource, pDesignated, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);

        System.out.println("Done");

    }


}
```

the errors that i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: E:\destFOLDER  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:123)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:278)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1225)
at pm.entitymanager.logic.file.Action.copy(Action.java:55)
at pm.entitymanager.logic.file.ApplicationLogic.main(ApplicationLogic.java:64)
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: General tip: if you get an error message and want us to figure out what the problem is, you should probably think about telling us what the error message actually **IS**.

Comment: Why do you write a copy that is already implemented in nio2?

Comment: Start by indenting your code, to make it readable, for us and for yourself. Then ask yourself why you copy the file twice.

Comment: @MarcB, I edited it with the errors

Comment: so did you actually READ the error? it says the file already exists.

Comment: @JBNizet, I do not copy it twice :/

Comment: @MarcB the folder exists not the files

Comment: I see the following line of code twice in the code you posted: `Files.copy(pSource, pDesignated, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES);`. Don't you? It would be more obvious if the code was properly indented.

Comment: because you're trying to copy to the folder, literally. this isn't like cmd where you can do `copy somefile.txt c:\somefolder` and it'll create the file inside that folder. you need absolute destinations: `copy somefile.txt c:\somefolder\somefile.txt`.

Comment: i'm currently trying to copy the folder ;/